# Python saving data values to a csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, save

Now this program reads data from a csv, sums the values per day, and calculates the cumulative values. In the next part, I want it to save the data to a new csv file.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict


def convert(data):
    try:
        return int(data)
    except ValueError:
        return 0


with open('Montdata1.csv', 'r') as file1:
        read_file = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=';')
        delheader = next(read_file)
        data = defaultdict(int)
        for line in read_file:
            valuedata = max(0, sum([convert(i) for i in line[1:5]]))
            data[line[0].split()[0]] += valuedata

        for key in OrderedDict(sorted(data.items())):
            print('{} {}'.format(key, data[key]))
        print("")
        previous_values = []
        for key, value in OrderedDict(sorted(data.items())).items():
            print('{} {}'.format(key, value + sum(previous_values)))
            previous_values.append(value)
```

It should be that in the column is the date, and in the second is the values. So it would be something like this:
[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmt43.png)

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't do anything:

```
with open('Datasave.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimeter= ' ')
    for row in spamreader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

Hope for some help
The data file as csv: https://files.fm/u/2vjppmgv
Data file in pastebin https://pastebin.com/Tw4aYdPc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use your original code and write to a csv file, you can see how I did it below:

```
with open('Datasave.csv', 'w') as df:
    writer = csv.writer(df, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
    for item in data:
        writer.writerow([item] + [data[item]])
```

With pandas:

```
#!/bin/python

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';')

df['Sum'] = df[df.columns[2:]].sum(axis=1)
new_df = df.groupby('Time').sum()

new_df['Sum'].to_frame().to_csv('new_data.csv', sep=';')
```

Output:

```
Time;Sum
1.1.2016;351087.0
2.1.2016;-2453.0
3.1.2016;0.0
```

With standard libraries:

```
import csv

dates={}

with open('data.csv', 'r') as df:
    df.readline()
    f = csv.reader(df, delimiter=';')
    for line in f:
        if line[0] not in dates:
            dates[line[0]] = sum(map(int, line[2:]))
        else:
            dates[line[0]] += sum(map(int, line[2:]))

with open('new_data.csv', 'w') as df:
    writer = csv.writer(df, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
    for date in dates:
        writer.writerow([date] + [dates[date]])
```

Output:

```
Time;Sum
1.1.2016;351087.0
2.1.2016;-2453.0
3.1.2016;0.0
```

Comment: Is it possible without pandas? I have tried to make this version with default libraries.
Also edited the wrong data files

Comment: I updated the data file, the first one was the actual file I'm working with, but the current is for the code. Hopefully it doesn't matter too much.
If you check my original code with the updated file, you see what the program prints, I was wanting the prints to go to a new file

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation; but I meant that the original code prints and does everything right, but I only want it to save the printed data to a new csv file. 
If this is possible, I'd massivly appreciate it

Comment: Assuming you're storing things in the `data` dict... I modified my code writing to csv to use that variable instead.

Comment: In your code you're never using the data variable when you're trying to write to the file. I assume that you want to.

Comment: It's not quite what I'm looking for. Your code saves the new_data like this: https://i.imgur.com/JYW0Leu.png  
But I'm hoping it to be like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmt43.png

Comment: It's not my code doing that, it's yours. All the last edit I made does is write your data to a CSV. Your data looks like that, so the CSV ends up like that.

Comment: Ah, I got it. My bad sorry, I thought that your code should do that.

Comment: @Armeija I'd appreciate a +1 or check mark if my code helped